# Как изменить текст в текстовом поле в колонтитулах Word Interop?

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop, interop

Делаю модуль генерации отчета в Word. Есть шаблон, скриншоты части которого представлен на картинках. Необходимо поменять текст в текстовых полях (т.е. разработал, проверил, номер, название_р) на тот, который приходит программе на вход. Эти текстовые поля находятся в колонтитулах.
Также выделенные красным текстовые поля являются элементами управления содержимым.
Я нашел, как изменить текст в колонтитуле,если он задается обычным текстом. Но здесь внутри колонтитула создается текстовое поле, поэтому такой способ не работает.
Я перепробовал различные способы изменения текста в данной ситуации - искал Shape объекты внутри колонтитулов, пытался работать через элементы управления содержимым (спойлер - не получилось, так как interop word не видит все, что находится в колонтитулах), пытался делать банальный Find.Execute, что тоже не работало из-за такой же причины, что и с элементами управления содержимым.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть ли какой-то способ достать эти текстовые поля из колонтитулов и заменить в них текст?

**Попытка 1**

```
Application app = new Application();
Document doc = app.Documents.Add("C:\\Users\\User1\\Documents\\номер1.docx", Visible: false);
for (int i=0; i<r2.KeyValues.Count;i++)
{
    app.Selection.Find.Execute("{"+r2.KeyValues[i].Key+"}");
    var rng = app.Selection.Range;
    rng.Text = r2.KeyValues[i].Value;
}
```

r2.KeyValues содержит список пар (ключ, значение), где ключ - это слово, которое надо поменять, значение - слово, на которое надо поменять ключ.

**Попытка 2**

```
for (int i = 0; i < r2.KeyValues.Count;i++)
{
    ContentControls controls = doc.SelectContentControlsByTitle('{'+r2.KeyValues[i].Key+'}');
    if (controls.Count > 0)
    {
        ContentControl control = controls[1];
        control.Range.Text = r2.KeyValues[i].Value;
    }            
}
```

**Попытки 3 и 4**

Пробовал еще через Headers Footers и StoryRanges, но примеры найти не могу.

Заранее благодарю за ответ

[image: 1]
[image: 2]

Answer (score 0):

вот:

```
using System;
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

namespace TestProjectWord
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Word.Application app = new Word.Application(); //Создаём новый Word.Application
            Word.Document doc = null; //Загружаем документ

            doc = app.Documents.Add(@"C:\Users\User1\Documents\номер1.docx", Visible: false);
            //Задаём параметры замены и выполняем замену.
            object findText = "{Что меняем}";
            object replaceWith = "На что меняем";
            object replace = 2;
            object tm = Type.Missing;

            object WH=Word.WdHeaderFooterIndex;
            WH колонтитул1лист = WH.wdHeaderFooterFirstPage;
            WH колонтитулысо2листа = WH.wdHeaderFooterPrimary;
            WH колонтитулычетныхлистов = WH.wdHeaderFooterEvenPages;
            // замена в верхнем колонтитуле
            // замена в верхнем колонтитуле на первом листе
            doc.Sections[1].Headers[колонтитул1лист].Range.Find.Execute(
            ref findText, ref tm, ref tm, ref tm, ref tm, ref tm, ref tm, ref tm, 
            ref tm, ref replaceWith, ref replace, ref tm, ref tm, ref tm, ref tm);
            // замена в верхнем колонтитуле на последующих листах
            doc.Sections[1].Headers[колонтитулысо2листа].Range.Find.Execute(
            ref findText, ref tm, ref tm, ref tm, ref tm, ref tm, ref tm, ref tm, 
            ref tm, ref replaceWith, ref replace, ref tm, ref tm, ref tm, ref tm);
            // замена в верхнем колонтитуле на четных листах
            doc.Sections[1].Headers[колонтитулычетныхлистов].Range.Find.Execute(
            ref findText, ref tm, ref tm, ref tm, ref tm, ref tm, ref tm, ref tm, 
            ref tm, ref replaceWith, ref replace, ref tm, ref tm, ref tm, ref tm);
            // замена в нижнем колонтитуле
            // замена в нижнем колонтитуле на первом листе
            doc.Sections[1].Footers[колонтитул1лист].Range.Find.Execute(
            ref findText, ref tm, ref tm, ref tm, ref tm, ref tm, ref tm, ref tm, 
            ref tm, ref replaceWith, ref replace, ref tm, ref tm, ref tm, ref tm);
            // замена в нижнем колонтитуле на последующих листах
            doc.Sections[1].Footers[колонтитулысо2листа].Range.Find.Execute(
            ref findText, ref tm, ref tm, ref tm, ref tm, ref tm, ref tm, ref tm, 
            ref tm, ref replaceWith, ref replace, ref tm, ref tm, ref tm, ref tm);
            // замена в нижнем колонтитуле на четных листах
            doc.Sections[1].Footers[колонтитулычетныхлистов].Range.Find.Execute(
            ref findText, ref tm, ref tm, ref tm, ref tm, ref tm, ref tm, ref tm, 
            ref tm, ref replaceWith, ref replace, ref tm, ref tm, ref tm, ref tm);
             
            //Открываем документ для просмотра.
            app.Visible = true;

        }
    }
}
```

ну и ваш пример:

```
using System;
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

namespace TestProjectWord
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Word.Application app = new Word.Application();//Создаём новый Word.Application
            Word.Document doc = app.Documents.Add(
                @"C:\Users\User1\Documents\номер1.docx", 
                Visible: false); //Загружаем документ
            object replace = 2;
            object tm = Type.Missing;
            object WH=Word.WdHeaderFooterIndex;
            WH колонтитул1лист = WH.wdHeaderFooterFirstPage;
            WH колонтитулысо2листа = WH.wdHeaderFooterPrimary;
            for (int i=0; i<r2.KeyValues.Count;i++)
            {
            object findText = "{"+r2.KeyValues[i].Key+"}"; // что меняем
            object replaceWith = r2.KeyValues[i].Value; // на что меняем
    // замена в нижнем колонтитуле на первом листе
            doc.Sections[1].Footers[колонтитул1лист].Range.Find.Execute(
            ref findText, ref tm, ref tm, ref tm, ref tm, ref tm, ref tm, ref tm, 
            ref tm, ref replaceWith, ref replace, ref tm, ref tm, ref tm, ref tm);
    // замена в нижнем колонтитуле на последующих листах
            doc.Sections[1].Footers[колонтитулысо2листа].Range.Find.Execute(
            ref findText, ref tm, ref tm, ref tm, ref tm, ref tm, ref tm, ref tm, 
            ref tm, ref replaceWith, ref replace, ref tm, ref tm, ref tm, ref tm);
            }
            //Открываем документ для просмотра.
            app.Visible = true;

        }
    }
}
```

[wdHeaderFooterPrimary](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word.wdheaderfooterindex?view=word-pia#Microsoft_Office_Interop_Word_WdHeaderFooterIndex_wdHeaderFooterPrimary) Возвращает верхний или нижний колонтитул на всех страницах, кроме первой страницы документа или раздела.

[wdHeaderFooterFirstPage](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word.wdheaderfooterindex?view=word-pia#Microsoft_Office_Interop_Word_WdHeaderFooterIndex_wdHeaderFooterPrimary) Возвращает первый верхний или нижний колонтитул в документе или разделе.

[wdHeaderFooterEvenPages](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word.wdheaderfooterindex?view=word-pia#Microsoft_Office_Interop_Word_WdHeaderFooterIndex_wdHeaderFooterPrimary) Возвращает все верхние и нижние колонтитулы на четных страницах.

файл для работы с word: [Microsoft Office 2010: Primary Interop Assemblies Redistributable](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3508) от Microsoft, распаковываем и получаем установочный файл, устанавливаем его и по пути c:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word\15.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c\ находим Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.dll

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).